# how to set single background for two text view

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a case in which I have to set the text in a design of calendar. on the top section of this calendar I must show the Month and in the middle section I should show the date.

but I have no idea How can I show two different things in one design . here is the design[image]. Please help.

Comment: You cab try to split your design image on two separate image, one for top and one for bottom, after that create from pictures ninepatch. Than put your textview to linear layout with vertical orientation and set background for every textview.

Comment: you mean I have to cut the uppar part and lower part ? isnt there any other way ?

Comment: if upper and lower part has different height, than you can catch situation when textview will run into background of second text view. Anyway you should create ninepatch from your img

Comment: I dont know How to create 9 patch , can hou create and attach files here ?>

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/cal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/monthTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:text="Month"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Date"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here `@mipmap/cal` is the background image of the calendar that you posted above in the question. Also, you might have to adjust the margins as per your needs.

Comment: I have done this , but its of no use, its seems like text views are sticking out of its bounds and making the linearlayout bigger then the size of background

Comment: You should create ninepatch from you background

Comment: how it is going to help me , 9Patch ?